# Is it possible to get a width in px from a div in a html page, without this property being manually set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Suppose I have a div in my page, that doesn't have a width property manually set.

A user can resize his window, and so this div has, visually, a new "size" (dynamic). Is this new size (in px value terms) available somewhere? Like, "div.getCurrentSize" or something like that?

So, is it possible to get this width value from this div using something like javascript?

Comment: you could use jQuery to get it - that helps a ton with dimensions and making sure what you get is cross-browser. http://api.jquery.com/width/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [jQuery dimensions](http://api.jquery.com/category/dimensions/) methods, e.g.

```
var w = $('#id').width();
```

Also note that it's not usually possible to obtain the dimensions of any element that's hidden.  If you set the `display` property to `none` then the dimensions will all read as zero.

Answer (score 1):

[outerWidth](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/)

> Description: Get the current computed width for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding and border.

Comment: Whats exactly the difference between outerWidth and width?

Comment: See the documentation in the link. It's about including the padding/border/margin in the calculation.

Comment: outerWidth includes padding and borders, width doesn't

Answer (score 0):

How about the standard javascript

```
(obj).offsetWidth
```